# jinja template adds extra line when if condition is not satisfied

Tags: ansible, jinja2

A `for loop` in my jinja template is like this

```
{% for m in grp %}
abc {{ m.length }}
      pqr
      xyz
{% if m.flag is defined and m.flag == "f" %}
      yes f {% endif %}    
{% for r in uv %}
      abcdef
{% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Now the problem is in some members of `grp` don't have the `flag` variable. Wherever `flag` is present, the `option true` line is getting added properly. But when if condition is not satisfied, it just adds one blank line. These 4 or 5 lines are supposed to be without extra blank lines otherwise the generated config file gets marked as invalid.
Can  anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `{% endif %}` to the next line

```
{% if m.flag is defined and m.flag == "f" %}
      yes f
{% endif %}
```

[Whitespace Control](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#whitespace-control) might be useful too.

> If you add a minus sign (-) to the start or end of a block (e.g. a For tag), a comment, or a variable expression, the whitespaces before or after that block will be removed.

```
{% if m.flag is defined and m.flag == "f" %}      yes f
{% endif -%}
```